# Understanding some loop code walking up a DisplayObject hierarchy

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

**Background:**
I am slogging through the wonderful (if woefully undocumented) [AS3SVGRenderer](https://github.com/LucasLorentz/AS3SVGRenderer) lib and have encountered some code that I don't understand.

The code below is from a Flex demo of the lib; "svgGroup" is a Spark `Group` and has an eventListener attached. When clicked, it returns the `SVGElement` instance which was clicked on. I am trying to understand this so I can get access to the `SVGElements` programatically.

The function below is called by the eventListener; it receives the `DisplayObject` which was clicked on as an arg.

`SVGElement` extends `Sprite`

---

```
    public static function getSVGElement(object:DisplayObject):SVGElement {
        while(object != null && !(object is SVGElement)){
            object = object.parent;
        }
        return object as SVGElement;
    }
```

---

**Question:**

Let me try to walk through a reading of it.

> while object isn't null AND object IS NOT an SVGElement
>
> ```
>     set object to its parent
> ```
>
> if object is null OR object IS an SVGElement then
>
> ```
>     break out of loop
>     return object
> ```

So essentially it is walking up the container until it finds an SVGElement instance. Do I have that right? So something like this:

`SVGElement` <- `DisplayObject` <- `DisplayObject`

---

```
    protected function svgGroup_clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        selectedElement = DisplayUtils.getSVGElement(e.target as DisplayObject);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. The `getSVGElement` function could also be rewritten recursively like this:

```
public static function getSVGElement(object:DisplayObject):SVGElement {
    if (object == null || object is SVGElement) {
        return object as SVGElement;
    } else {
        return getSVGElement(object.parent);
    }
}
```

Which might be somewhat more understandable, if also somewhat less efficient.

Comment: thanks! I understood your version easily. I think the NOT (IS object) construct (`!(object is SVGElement))` was breaking my brain.